# Adding object to JSON file

Tags: c#, json

I'm creating a software on which I added a profiles feature where the user can create profile to load his informations faster. To store these informations, I'm using a JSON file, which contains as much objects as there are profiles.

Here is the format of the JSON file when a profile is contained (not the actual one, an example) :

```
{
  "Profile-name": {
    "form_email": "example@example.com",
    //Many other informations...
  }
}
```

Here is the code I'm using to write the JSON and its content :

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("profiles.json");
                    dynamic profiles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                    if (profiles == null)
                    {
                        File.WriteAllText(jsonFilePath, "{}");
                        json = File.ReadAllText(jsonFilePath);
                        profiles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Profile_Name>>(json);
                    }
                    profiles.Add(profile_name.Text, new Profile_Name { form_email = form_email.Text });
                    var newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(profiles, Formatting.Indented);
                    File.WriteAllText(jsonFilePath, newJson);
                    profile_tr.Nodes.Add(profile_name.Text, profile_name.Text);
                    debug_tb.Text += newJson;
```

But when the profiles.json file is completely empty, the profile is successfully written, but when I'm trying to ADD a profile when another one already exists, I get this error :
`The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Add(string, Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken)' has some invalid arguments` on the `profiles.Add();` line.
By the way, you can notice that I need to add `{}` by a non-trivial way in the file if it's empty, maybe it has something to do with the error ?
The expected output would be this JSON file :

```
{
  "Profile-name": {
    "form_email": "example@example.com",
    //Many other informations...
  },
  "Second-profile": {
    "form_email": "anotherexample@example.com"
    //Some other informations...
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe this `Dictionary<string, Profile_Name>` should be `List<Dictionary<string, Profile_Name>>`

Comment: And I'm hoping your Json is actually putting the Profile-Name object in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found by reading my code again, so I just replaced  `dynamic profiles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);` to `dynamic profiles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Profile_Name>>(json);`.
But it still don't fix the non-trivial way I use to add the `{}` to my file...

Answer (score 0):

The object the first DeserializeObject method returns is actually a JObject, but below you deserialize it as a Dictionary. You shouldn't be mixing the types, choose either one.

If you use the JObject then to add objects you need to convert them to JObjects:

```
profiles.Add(profile_name.Text, JObject.FromObject(new Profile_Name { form_email = form_email.Text }));
```

In both cases, when the profile is null you just need to initialize it:

```
if (profiles == null)
{
    profiles = new JObject(); // or new Dictionary<string, Profile_Name>();
}
```